# How to customise the popup message when registering for remote push notifications

Tags: ios, onesignal

Is there a way to customise the popup message when registering for remote push notifications with One Signal's iOS native SDK?

When registering like this:

```
[OneSignal promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse:^(BOOL accepted) {
  NSLog(@"Accepted Notifications?: %d", accepted);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a system dialog which cannot be customized.

You can find which permission alerts message you *can* customize [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).

Comment: do you happen to know with which key I could observe this alert ?

Comment: what tyou want to do ?

Comment: This is what I was looking for: OSPermissionSubscriptionState* status = [OneSignal getPermissionSubscriptionState];
status.permissionStatus.hasPrompted